# Swagger validation error "Data does not match any schemas from 'oneOf'"

Tags: java, rest, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

Getting Swagger validation error '*Data does not match any schemas from 'oneOf'*' for one of my Rest API route, I have used annotations, this is my code

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Submit items")         
@ApiImplicitParam(paramType="body",dataType="Object",required=true,value="submit",name="body")
public <T extends Object> T submit(Request request, Response response) { 
Object cResponse = null;
// some codes
return  (T) cResponse;
}
```

But, this error can be fixed by using a POGO object instead of T, like bellow

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Submit items")                
@ApiImplicitParam(paramType="body",dataType="Order",required=true,value="submit",name="body")
public Order submit(Request request, Response response) { 
Order cResponse = null;
// some codes
return  cResponse;
}
```

According to requirements i have to stick with T implementation, please help me to get this fix with generic return type

Thnanx

Comment: Which version of swagger-core do you use? And which JAX-RS framework?

Comment: Swagger 1.2 and framework called RestExpress

Comment: swagger-core is tuned to work with jax-rs frameworks and won't parse anything else without your own customized Reader. The handling of generics has been vastly improved in swagger-core 1.5, but if you don't use jax-rs, you're out of luck.